# Expectation of covariance in derivation of Kalman filter

Tags: covariance, expected-value, kalman-filter

I'm working through the derivation of the Kalman filter equations from [this paper](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~rmf25/papers/Understanding%20the%20Basis%20of%20the%20Kalman%20Filter.pdf) (or [alternative source here](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/MSP.2012.2203621)) and I'm unsure of the derivation of the state prediction covariance (equation 2 in the paper).

I understand that we want $\mathbf{P}_{t|t-1}$ to be the covariance of the error of the prediction from the true value, i.e. $\text{Cov}\left(\mathbf{x}_t-\hat{\mathbf{x}}_{t|t-1}\right)$, but the author proceeds as follows:

$\mathbf{P}_{t|t-1} = \text{E}\left[\text{Cov}\left(\mathbf{x}_t-\hat{\mathbf{x}}_{t|t-1}\right)\right] = \text{E}\left[\left(\mathbf{x}_t-\hat{\mathbf{x}}_{t|t-1}\right)\left(\mathbf{x}_t-\hat{\mathbf{x}}_{t|t-1}\right)^\top\right]$

My question is, why do we need the expectation? i.e., why is this not just

$\mathbf{P}_{t|t-1} = \text{Cov}\left(\mathbf{x}_t-\hat{\mathbf{x}}_{t|t-1}\right) = \left(\mathbf{x}_t-\hat{\mathbf{x}}_{t|t-1}\right)\left(\mathbf{x}_t-\hat{\mathbf{x}}_{t|t-1}\right)^\top$

This would seem to work through the derivation in the same way to give the same end result.

Put another way, what's the expectation of a covariance?

Comment: Where does the author do this: ${P}_{t|t-1} $ $= \text{E}\left[\text{Cov}\left({x}_t-\hat{{x}}_{t|t-1}\right)\right]$ $ = \text{E}\left[\left(x_t-\hat{x}_{t|t-1}\right)\left(x_t-\hat{x}_{t|t-1}\right)^T \right]$? Sorry to be dopey, but I can't seem to spot where that is.

Comment: However, in the meantime note that $\left(x_t-\hat{x}_{t|t-1}\right)\left(x_t-\hat{x}_{t|t-1}\right)^T$ is a random variable. The covariance is in fact its expectation, not the random quantity you have there. [see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Generalizations)

Comment: To be clear, it's the middle term in the quoted equality that I have a problem with. I can't see where it's put like that. $P_{t|t-1}=\text{E}\left[\left(x_t-\hat{x}_{t|t-1}\right)\left(x_t-\hat{x}_{t|t-1}\right)^T \right]$ is fine.

Comment: @Glen_b, I see, thank you. I think that I am just confused about the notation. So when we derive PCA (from [here](http://luthuli.cs.uiuc.edu/~daf/courses/CS-498-DAF-PS/Lecture%209%20-%20PCA.pdf), starting on slide 13) we say that $\mathbf{W}\mathbf{X}=\mathbf{Y}$ such that the covariance matrix is diagonalised, i.e. $N\mathbf{I}=\left(\mathbf{W}\mathbf{X}\right){\left(\mathbf{W}\mathbf{X}\right)}^{\top}$ and then on slide 15 we replace $\mathbf{X}\mathbf{X}^\top$ with $\text{Cov}\left(\mathbf{X}\right)$. Why do we omit the expectation here? Is it just for clarity?

Comment: That's a whole new question. See slide 12 for how they define covariance -- but note that's *sample*  covariance (at least it is when $z$ is centered), so we replace expectation by an average. See that factor of 1/N? That's the averaging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like this is just a small confusion about the definition of covariance.

In the case of random variables, the variance-covariance matrix is an expectation:

$$\text{Cov}(X)=\operatorname{E}((X - \mu)(X - \mu)^{\operatorname{T}})$$

See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Generalizations).

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up. I think that the difference between sample covariance and the covariance of a random variable is becoming clearer.